# How to updated cascading parameter in blazor WASM main layout

Tags: parameters, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor WASM I want to update a parameter inside `MainLayout` from a button inside `Index` page component, I'm using cascading parameter and here's my `MainLayout` looks like:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<main>

    <CascadingValue Value="@total" Name="TotalPara">

        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <h6>Total sum: @total</h6>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>

    </CascadingValue>

</main>
```

```
@code{
    decimal total = 0;
}
```

Index.blazor component:

```
Click the button to update total value <br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="UpdateValue">Update Total</button>

@code{

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "TotalPara")] decimal total { get; set; }

    private void UpdateValue()
    {
        total = total + 10;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

When I click the update total button the value changed but the UI not updated?

Comment: `decimal` is a Value Type. Wrap `total` in a class.

Comment: @HH Can you make it more clear or put an answer please

Answer (score 0):

When you update a cascading parameter from a child component the parent in not notified. To achieve what you want you can create a class that keeps the state and exposes an event Action to notify the parent when the state is changed:

```cs
public class MainLayoutState
{
    private decimal _total = 0;

    public decimal Total => _total;

    public event Action OnTotalChange;

    public void UpdateValue()
    {
        _total += 10;
        OnTotalChange?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**MainLayout.razor**:

```
@implements IDisposable

<main>
    <CascadingValue Value="state">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <h6>Total sum: @state.Total</h6>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </CascadingValue>
</main>

@code {
    private MainLayoutState state = new MainLayoutState();    
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        state.OnTotalChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        state.OnTotalChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

**Index.razor**:

```
Click the button to update total value <br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">Update Total</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private MainLayoutState MainLayoutState { get; set; }
 
    private void OnClick()
    {
        MainLayoutState.UpdateValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the second option. Passing a component reference around (including cascading) isn't often a good idea.  Why?  1. You're passing around an object that you are not in control of - it's owned by the renderer. 2. You're exposing functionality [that can be called/changed/triggered] but shouldn't be exposed.

Comment: It might be appropriate for some scenarios. For example in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-data-across-a-component-hierarchy) there is an example tab implementation where the parent `TabSet` component provides itself as a cascading value so that it is then picked up by the descendent `Tab` components. This is why I decided to also include this method in the answer.

Comment: [Polite] Dimitris - I did qualify with " isn't often a good idea".  The Tab example could just as easily be coded using your second option.  [Tongue-in-cheek]MS don't always write the best code in the world! It may have been carried forward from the early days of Blazor.  I personally always use the second option - it separates out state - which you can persist if you want. :-)

Comment: I'm also suspicious of altering children of passed parameters.  Seems potentially risky.  For example, if you are firing changes off of input on a connection with high latency, you could end up with concurrency issues. (I don't know this, but it seems like. . . )