# ASP.NET Core Blazor: Cascading Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Here is the scenario I want to retrieve the child component parameters for the use of the parrant component.
Code for parent component:

```
    [Parameter]
    public List<TItem>? DataItems { get; set; }
    public List<ColumnDefinition>? Columns { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    public void AddColumn(ColumnDefinition columnDefinition)
    {
        if (Columns is null)
            Columns = new();
        Columns.Add(columnDefinition);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Code for child component:

```
    [CascadingParameter]
    public DataGridComponent<TItem>? ContainerDataGridComponent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public required ColumnDefinition ColumnDefinition { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        ContainerDataGridComponent?.AddColumn(ColumnDefinition);
    }
```

launch code:

```
<DataGridComponent DataItems="PersonDtos" TItem="PersonDto">
    <ColumnComponent TItem="PersonDto" ColumnDefinition="@(new(){DataField = " FirstName", Caption="First Name" })" ></ColumnComponent>
    <ColumnComponent TItem="PersonDto" ColumnDefinition="@(new(){DataField = "LastName", Caption = "Last Name"})" ></ColumnComponent>
    <ColumnComponent TItem="PersonDto" ColumnDefinition="@(new(){DataField = "CreatedDate", Caption = "Created Date"})" ></ColumnComponent>
    <ColumnComponent TItem="PersonDto" ColumnDefinition="@(new(){DataField = "UpdatedDate", Caption = "Updated Date"})" ></ColumnComponent>
</DataGridComponent>
```

My problem:
this property is always null

```
[CascadingParameter]
    public DataGridComponent<TItem>? ContainerDataGridComponent { get; set; }
```

......
What do I have to do?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes it's c#, I had to disable the translator to put it

Comment: Have you checked out QuickGrid by the Blazor Team -  the repo sis here with all the code.  It may change your approach on how to code a data grid. - https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/

Comment: I see their github, but I wonder where the problem comes from @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: Where and how did you define the CascadingValue component?

Comment: I didn't do CascadingValue @Yoeri

Comment: You cannot get a CascadingParameter value without defining a CascadingValue ... so its obvious you get null.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing because this is what you should have based on the code you've supplied.  Are you doing the cascade in Grid?

```cs
public class ColumnDefinition
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

*GridItem*

```cs
@typeparam TItem
<div class="alert alert-primary">
@ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public Grid<TItem>? ContainerDataGridComponent { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public required ColumnDefinition ColumnDefinition { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ContainerDataGridComponent?.AddColumn(this.ColumnDefinition);
    }
}
```

*Grid*

```
@typeparam TItem
<h3>Grid</h3>
<CascadingValue Value="this">
        @ChildContent
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            Registered columns : @Columns.Count()
        </div>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<TItem>? DataItems { get; set; }
    public List<ColumnDefinition>? Columns { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    public void AddColumn(ColumnDefinition columnDefinition)
    {
        if (Columns is null)
            Columns = new();
        Columns.Add(columnDefinition);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

And the page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<Grid TItem="int">
    <GridItem TItem="int" ColumnDefinition="@(new ColumnDefinition { Name="Fred"})">Hello 1</GridItem>
    <GridItem TItem="int" ColumnDefinition="@(new ColumnDefinition { Name="Fred"})">Hello 2</GridItem>
    <GridItem TItem="int" ColumnDefinition="@(new ColumnDefinition { Name="Fred"})">Hello 3</GridItem>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In this instance you don't need to cascade the whole component, just the registration method, as an `Action` like this:

*GridItem*

```cs
@typeparam TItem
<div class="alert alert-primary">
@ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Action<ColumnDefinition>? Register { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public required ColumnDefinition ColumnDefinition { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.Register?.Invoke(this.ColumnDefinition);
    }
}
```

*Grid*

```cs
@typeparam TItem
<h3>Grid</h3>
<CascadingValue Value="this.RegisterColumn">
        @ChildContent
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            Registered columns : @Columns.Count()
        </div>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<TItem>? DataItems { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private readonly List<ColumnDefinition> Columns = new();

    private void RegisterColumn(ColumnDefinition columnDefinition)
    {
        if (!this.Columns.Any(item => item == columnDefinition ))
            Columns.Add(columnDefinition);

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it works with CascadingValue thanks. but I can't understand it doesn't work in the mercrosoft documentation they happen without using CascadingValue. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-data-across-a-component-hierarchy

Comment: Check the TabSet code you'll find the cascade.  This also explains why you're cascading the component.  See the commentary on this answer on why cascading components isn't often the best approach.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75644669/13065781

Comment: yes you are right, I misread TabSet