# Update element in root component when child component changes object

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I have a Blazor Webassembly project with a custom `razor` component.

```cs
@page "/resume"
@using Resume.Shared.Dto.Resume
@layout ResumeEditorLayout
 
@inject ResumeDto ResumeDto

<CascadingValue Value="ResumeDto" IsFixed="true">
    <div class="row d-flex">
        <div class="col fixed-width fields">
            <h1>A: @ResumeDto.Personalia.FirstName</h1>
            <Personalia />
            
            <h1>B: @ResumeDto.Personalia.LastName</h1>
            <Input @bind-Value="ResumeDto.Personalia.LastName" Label="Last name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
```

The `ResumeDto` class is registered as a singleton:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ResumeDto>();
```

The razor component also uses a `Personalia` component that looks like this:

```cs
@using Resume.Shared.Dto.Resume

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <Input @bind-Value="ResumeDto.Personalia.FirstName" Label="First name" />
        <Input @bind-Value="ResumeDto.Personalia.Email" Label="Email address" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public ResumeDto ResumeDto { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This results in a simple web page that looks like this:

[image]

When I type something in the `Firstname` input field I expected it to update the first `<h1>` tag. But this doesn't happen. This seems to be because the input fields are inside a child component.

But when I type something in the `Lastname` input field, then I see that the second `<h1>` tag gets updates immediately.

I want to abstract parts away in child components. But in a way that the main parent component's `ResumeDto` is up to date. I thought that `CascadingParameter` would pass the object as reference.

But why doesn't my first `<h1>` get updated doesn't get updated when I type something in the input field? It does work when I put the input fields directly into the page. But like I said, I would like to abstract certain parts into child components.

How can I fix this issue?

---

### Input.razor (custom component)

I also use a custom component to render the `input` fields with a `label`. That looks like this:

```cs
<div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <label for="@Id" class="form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline-block">@Label</label>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Value" @oninput="e => Value = e.Value?.ToString()" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    private string? _value;

    [Parameter]
    public string? Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private string Id { get; set; } = $"id_{Guid.NewGuid():N}";
}
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75644669/10839134) might help.

Comment: That answer will probably work. But if I understand it correctly that means I have to create a callback event for each and every property... That seems a bit cumbersome if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to make a multi-part edit form.  The problems with such a design is in component to component communications.

How does component X know that the model has been changed by component Y?  You start wiring up callbacks, and ..... get into a mess with calls to `stateHasChanged`.

This answer is based on implementing some code patterns covered in this Repo - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.EditContext.

The key is to use the `EditContext` as the cascade (`Model` is the data) and `OnFieldChanged` to update components when a field is changed.

So assuming we have a `PersonEditContext` based on a `PersonData` record that looks like this:

```cs
public record PersonRecord
{     
    public string? FirstName { get; init; }
    public string? LastName { get; init; }
}
```

This is how to refactor your `Input` to inherit directly from `InputText`:

```cs
@inherits InputText

<div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <label class="form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline-block">@this.Label</label>
    @this.content
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Label { get; set; }

    // this gets the render code from the parent InputText class
    private RenderFragment content => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

And if you want to update `oninput` then this:

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
@inherits InputText

<div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <label class="form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline-block">@this.Label</label>
    @this.InputContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool UpdateOnInput { get; set; }
    
    protected RenderFragment InputContent => (RenderTreeBuilder builder) =>
    {
        var eventName = this.UpdateOnInput
            ? "oninput"
            : "onchange";

        builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, this.AdditionalAttributes);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.CssClass))
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", this.CssClass);

        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", CurrentValueAsString);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, eventName, EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));
        builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
        builder.AddElementReferenceCapture(5, __inputReference => Element = __inputReference);
        builder.CloseElement();
    };
}
```

`Personlia.razor` can now look like this.  Note we capture the editContext and then cast the model to `PersonEditContext`.  `ArgumentNullException` raises exceptions if we get it wrong.

```cs
@implements IDisposable
<div class="row bg-light m-3 p-2 border border-dark">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <InputControl Label="First Name" @bind-Value=this.model.FirstName />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <InputControl Label="Last Name" @bind-Value=this.model.LastName />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private PersonEditContext model = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(editContext);
        var context = editContext.Model as PersonEditContext;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(context);
        model = context;
        editContext.OnFieldChanged += OnModelChanged;
    }

    private void OnModelChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        => StateHasChanged();
    
    public void Dispose()
        => editContext.OnFieldChanged -= OnModelChanged;
}
```

Here's a simple display component:

```cs
@implements IDisposable

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <pre>First Name: @this.model.FirstName</pre>
    <pre>Last Name: @this.model.LastName</pre>
    <pre>Edit State: @(this.model.IsDirty ? "Dirty" : "Clean")</pre>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private PersonEditContext model = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(editContext);
        var context = editContext.Model as PersonEditContext;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(context);
        model = context;
        editContext.OnFieldChanged += OnModelChanged;
    }

    private void OnModelChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        => StateHasChanged();

    public void Dispose()
        => editContext.OnFieldChanged -= OnModelChanged;
}
```

And `Index` edit form.

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@inject ResumeDto ResumeDto

<div class="row d-flex">
    <EditForm EditContext=this.editContext>

        <RecordEditContextTracker RecordEditContext=this.model />

        <Personalia />

        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
            <InputControl Label="First Name" @bind-Value=this.model.FirstName />
        </div>

        <PersonDisplay />

    </EditForm>

</div>

@code {
    private PersonEditContext model = new(new());
    private EditContext? editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(model);
        editContext.OnFieldChanged += OnModelChanged;
    }

    private void OnModelChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        => StateHasChanged();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (editContext is not null)
            editContext.OnFieldChanged -= OnModelChanged;
    }
}
```

You can also see in the EditContext repo how to deal with edit state for button control and form locking.

I've temporarily published a working version of this code to [this Repo](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO75795531).

[image]

Comment: Yes, `Input` is a custom component. I've added the code in my post

Comment: OK.  Here's the answer I promised.  It's detailed: your SO profile suggests you're an experienced programmer.  It uses the ` INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern as Dimitris suggests in his answer, and the Blazor Notification pattern using events for inter component communications.  I've also included some code on how you can refactor `Input` to inherit directly from `InputText`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I have things working using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

> But if I understand it correctly that means I have to create a
> callback event for each and every property... That seems a bit
> cumbersome if that is the case.

You can have one callback for all properties like this:

```cs
public class Personalia
{
    private string? _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName ?? string.Empty;
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    private string? _email;

    public string Email
    {
        get => _email ?? string.Empty;
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action? OnChange;

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

Also if `ResumeDto` class is registered as a singleton then you don't need to use `CascadingValue`. The child component can inject it as well.

In your page:

```
@page "/resume"
@using Resume.Shared.Dto.Resume
@layout ResumeEditorLayout
@implements IDisposable
 
@inject ResumeDto ResumeDto

<div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col fixed-width fields">
        <h1>A: @ResumeDto.Personalia.FirstName</h1>
        <Personalia />
        
        <h1>B: @ResumeDto.Personalia.LastName</h1>
        <Input @bind-Value="ResumeDto.Personalia.LastName" Label="Last name" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ResumeDto.Personalia.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ResumeDto.Personalia.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
@using Resume.Shared.Dto.Resume

@inject ResumeDto ResumeDto

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <Input @bind-Value="ResumeDto.Personalia.FirstName" Label="First name" />
        <Input @bind-Value="ResumeDto.Personalia.Email" Label="Email address" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
}
```

This should work.

(Very similar to how [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is implemented.)